# System.Activator.CreateInstance - Keep Focus

Tags: c#, activator

I'm using the following code to launch an instance of Autodesk Inventor from a Windows form:

```
            // Launch Inventor in Silent Mode
        Type inventorAppType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Inventor.Application");
        m_inventorApp = System.Activator.CreateInstance(inventorAppType) as Inventor.Application;

        m_inventorApp.Visible = false;
```

My issue is the hidden instance of Inventor steals the focus from the Windows form. I can't interact with the launching form at all until the instance of Inventor is closed. 
I also tried showing a secondary form window while Inventor is active, this works but it can't be manipulated either until the Inventor instance is closed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like you are calling `ShowDialog` and its a modal form, have you tried `Show` instead?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using System.Activator.CreateInstance() instead of the easier Process.Start() method?

Comment: System.Activator is what the Inventor API documentation refers to.